# Dynamically set image src from JSON

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to set the image tag src from a JSON file in React.Js

In a JSON file, I have the details about the images as,

imageRepo.json

```
[
{
  "image" : "../img2.jpg"
},

{
    "image" : "../img1.jpg"
}
]
```

Am importing the JSON file into Js file using the code

`import DataImport from '../imageRepo.json'`

After importing am using the following code to iterate through the JSON file and updating the SRC of an image tag.

```
DataImport.map((item)=>{
    return(<div align="center">
    <img src={item.image} />
    </div>)
}
```

but am not able to achieve the desired output. Image is not loading in the page. I tried using require also as,

```
 <img src={require(item.image)} />
```

this results in an error.

Comment: Can you show whole code? I think something is missing

Comment: The first example looks like it should work, assuming the path to the image is correct. You're using relative paths to the image ('../' means up one folder from the current path).. is that really where the images are?

Comment: The below code works: ```<img src={require('../img1.jpg')} />```

Comment: What is the generated HTML with your first approach? From a technical point of view, it looks right. Have you checked in the browser if the network requests for the images have the right path?

Comment: Yeah, actually i tried adding some additional keys to the JSON and able to retrieve the values